# Indexed views on SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008-r2, view, indexed-view

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 database containing a very huge table that we use for reporting. Every night around 40,000 records are inserted into the table. I read in many articles that Indexed views are suitable for OLAP or Warehouse databases, not for transaction tables.

My goal is not to query the whole table, but to query a subset, say last 3 months data. Don't want to use triggers to create a subset. Would an indexed view be suitable for my scenario ? If not, any better ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

You might need to check some repercussions about using an indexed view. Here are some details of some items to consider before. http://msdotnetbuddy.blogspot.com/2010/12/indexed-view-in-mssql-server.html

You could also partition your big table, into let's say having only quarterly data. You would only query on a subset. If that is not an option, you could also create a temporary cache table, that only contains data specific for this report.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an indexed view, you will need to use the "with schemabinding" keywords, you can put this into any search engine to find the implications of using this.